# The ControlToValidate property of 'passwordCompare' cannot be blank

Tags: asp.net, repeater, comparevalidator

In my page I have repeater using which I dynamically generate two textboxes & I have one compare validator.

Now for this validator I want to set ControlTovalidate & ControlToCompare.
Id of both will come from two textboxes which are generated dynamically.

So while binding these textboxes to repeater I am setting both properties of validator But error comes as "The ControlToValidate property of 'passwordCompare' cannot be blank."

```
<asp:repeater id="repeater" runat="server" onitemdatabound="BoundProperty">
  <itemtemplate>
     <asp:panel id="panelProperty" runat="server" cssclass="prop">
           <asp:textbox id="textboxOrg" runat="server" cssclass="edit" visible="false"/>
    </asp:panel>
  </itemtemplate>
</asp:repeater>
<asp:comparevalidator id="passwordCompare" runat="server" controltovalidate="" controltocompare="" errormessage="CompareValidator"></asp:comparevalidator>
```

Comment: You can use a `CustomValidator` which is the only validator that allows to leave that property empty.

Comment: You can set the initial value of any control and change it on run time. Or use as suggested by @TimSchmelter

Comment: @TimSchmelter can you explain what you are saying ?

Comment: @शेखर I will not have any textbox initially

Comment: @vaibhavshah: what should i say? There is another type of validator, the [`CustomValidator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). You can use it without specifying the [`ControlToValidate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basevalidator.controltovalidate(v=vs.100).aspx)(_"must be set to the ID of an input control for all validation controls except the CustomValidator control"_). It allows to validate multiple controls or to apply a complex validation logic.

Comment: add two hidden field to page and place id of that fields in comparevalidator initially

Comment: @TimSchmelter cant I set both properties while I create textboxes dynamically ?

Comment: or dynamically create comparevalidator at runtime

Comment: @vaibhavshah: normally it should work, but then you should show the code that you use to assign the `ControlToValidate`. Maybe you are not using the same ID on every postback or you don't create the dynamical controls on every postback. Or you do that too late, i guess `Page_Init` is the latest stage where you can do that if you want to assign the `ControlToValidate`.